# How long does it take for the "Give Valentine" to reset on your neighbor's character?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

This is my first Valentine's Day event with Tapped Out.  How long does it takes once someone gives a Valentine to your neighbor's character before you can give them another one?

Many of my neighbors do not seem to have any characters which allow you to give them a Valentine, so they are just idling and I cannot gain any hearts or experience from them at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally they clear when they get collected.

An active player will get the hearts more quickly, thereby clearing any characters with Valentines right after they have been received.

If someone is less active, you may not be able to give them Valentines because their other friends have already filled up all of their characters.

Since the update is relatively recent, it's possible you can't give Valentines to some players because they may not have updated their game to the newer version yet.

Comment: `An active player will get the hearts more quickly, thereby clearing any characters with Valentines right after they have been received` Aha, I think that's the key. I just saw some Valentines appear in my own town, so that must be how they get cleared - it's not on any character per se, just shows up around the town. Thank you!